# Update Word 2013 SEQ fields

Tags: field, seq, word-2013

I'm writing a VBA macro to update ONLY SEQ fields in Word 2013 documents. I designed it to use GoTo to visit each SEQ field one at a time from start to end of the document (NOT Update All) to ensure that I skip other field types. I'm struggling to make it loop for each SEQ field until the end of the document is reached. I want it to work in any document, regardless of bookmarks or other end markers.

Here's the code I have so far (With comments):

ActiveWindow.View.FieldShading = wdFieldShadingAlways
'go to top of document
   Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
'Go To the first SEQ field

```
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToField, Which:=wdGoToNext, Count:=1, Name:="SEQ"
```

'    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting

'as long as there are more field codes, update this one and go to the next one
Do While Selection.GoToNext.wdGoToField = True
    Selection.Fields.Update
Loop

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late, but your question came up when I was looking for the same answer. :-)

For flexibility, the actual work is done as a function, where the field code is received as a string. That way I can call the function with any desired field code, not necessarily a specific SEQ or any field code at all.

```
Function UpdateSpecificFields(MyFieldCode As String)

Dim MyField As Field

    For Each MyField In ActiveDocument.Fields

'        Debug.Print """" & MyField.Code & """" & MyField.Result

        If InStr(1, MyField.Code, MyFieldCode) <> 0 Then
            MyField.Update
        End If

    Next MyField

End Function
```

We're looping through all the fields within the active document. You could include a test of whether `MyField.Type = wdFieldSequence` to reduce the unnecessary work.

The InStr is there in case of odd spacing; sometimes the field creator might include an extra space before or after the code itself, so I didn't want to be too literal. (I suppose there should have been a `trim()` to get rid of said spaces but I was getting a little lazy.)

Usage: Call the function from a sub.

```
Sub UpdateSEQQs()
    UpdateSpecificFields ("SEQ Qs")
End Sub
```

I have a `SEQ` called `Qs`, so you can see how it was called above. Hope this helps someone!